# Stop second map script running with window.matchMedia

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps, hide

we're putting together a site for a client, this site uses two maps but one gets hidden on mobile, this causes the second map to work but not load the terrain only the location pin.

I'm quite new to javascript so is there a way to stop the 1st map script running while allowing the second one just to run on mobile? I've been advised to use **window.matchMedia** but not how to use it.

Any ideas?

Here's the map script we are using. Along with the window.matchMedia script I was given.

```
    <!--- Window.matchMedia Script --->

<script>

    function myFunction(x) {

    if (x.matches) { // If media query matches

       document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#ff5353";

   } else {

       document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#ad00ff";

   }

        }

        var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1500px)")

            myFunction(x) // Call listener function at run time

                x.addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener function on state changes

</script>

<!--- Gmap Script --->

  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API KEY&callback=initMap"
  type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var geocoder;
var map;
var address = "Bideford,Devon";

function initMap() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    zoomControl: true,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    scaleControl: false,
    scrollwheel: true,
    panControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    draggable : true,
    overviewMapControl: false,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      styles: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    },
    navigationControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    styles:[
    {
        "featureType": "all",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "saturation": 36
            },
            {
                "color": "#c9bd88"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 40
            },
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "all",
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            },
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 16
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "all",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 20
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 17
            },
            {
                "weight": 1.2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 20
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 21
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 17
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 29
            },
            {
                "weight": 0.2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.arterial",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 18
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.local",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 16
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 19
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 17
            }
        ]
    }
]
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
  map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map2"), myOptions);
  if (geocoder) {
    geocoder.geocode({
      'address': address
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
          map2.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: '<b>' + address + '</b>',
            size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50)
          });

          var iconBase = 'https://daks2k3a4ib2z.cloudfront.net/597f0a54250f3500013ebc97/5992e4b5e91d6100019b55c5_'
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            map: map,
            title: address,
            icon: iconBase + 'gmap_icon_bg.png',
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
          });

          var iconBase2 = 'https://daks2k3a4ib2z.cloudfront.net/597f0a54250f3500013ebc97/5992e4b5e91d6100019b55c5_'
          var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            map: map2,
            title: address,
            icon: iconBase + 'gmap_icon_bg.png',
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map2, marker2);
          });

        } else {
          alert("No results found");
        }
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
}
//google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

   </script>
```

Thanks in advance, 
Jamie